# Prototype Cell - Accessibility order of elements

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, voiceover

I created a prototype cell which has three element - UILabel , UIButton(image - radio-button) and UILabel as shown below. also cell has Disclosure indicator. [image]

When I enable voice over. it reads "Test Data, Label4, button(for accessory) and then it reads radio-button" for UIButton. I want it to read in actual order - "Test Data, radio-button, Label4, button(for accessory)". If I add more labels in Cell then also it reads all labels first then UIButton.

Answer (score 1):

Add the elements in the order that you want them read to the `accessibilityElements` property. For example:

```
view.accessibilityElements = [leftLabel, radioBtn, rightLabel]
```

I found these two links to be good resources:

https://www.captechconsulting.com/blogs/accessibility---making-your-app-usable-for-everyone-part-2

https://ayeohyes.wordpress.com/2015/06/26/accessibility-in-ios-voiceover/